# Blazor: @ref usage confuses visual studio. How to ignore?

Tags: razor, blazor, resharper, blazor-webassembly, ref

Whenever I use the @ref syntax in blazor, visual studio gives me a ton of green underlines on my blazor components that use @ref.

Is there a way to disable this warning?  Is it resharper maybe?

Example image here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKkdo.jpg

Comment: You should post the error message and in the future try to include the code in text format not just a image it helps us replicate your problem with a little less typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is your `_tableRef` is non-nullable.
Try adding a `?` :

```
@code {
    ProjectUserJobRolesTable? _tableRef;
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Making it nullable did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can enable/disable null warnings at project level with these setting in .csproj file

To disable

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

To enable

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```